# wchar_t clashing with unsigned short

Tags: c++

I am updating our libraries to a newer version and have hit a compilation error:

```
ClassName &ReturnClass::FuncName(wchar_t *,size_t)' : member function already defined or declared
```

However it is previously defined as this:

```
ClassName &ReturnClass::FuncName(unsigned short *,size_t)'
```

And we have `wchar_t` as a `typedef` of `unsigned short` which seems to be causing the issue.

I have tried using the compiler option `wchar_t` but that causes masses of errors in the library when it sees the `typedef`.

I am using nmake to build the code in Windows and MSDEV as a code editor.

Has anyone seen this sort of thing before?  How did you solve it?

Comment: Try removing the `typedef` and setting the compiler option `/Zc:wchar_t`, this tells VC to treat `wchar_t` as a built-in type.

Comment: But the typedef is in the library code, I should not really be modifying that

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the typedef is in the MS code, not the library code!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the issue has been resolved.  The required compiler option was `/Zc:wchar_t` and not just `wchar_t', although that did resolve the initial issue.

I wsa under the impression that the '/Zc' bit was MS specific and was not required when directly using the clr compiler - DOH!